# Cant install Magento 2.3.2 on wamp server 3.1.9

Tags: magento2, wamp

I have put the magento folder in www of my wampserver and created a databas folder in the wamp server but when try to access the magento on my local host (http://localhost/magento/) i get these errors in the apache error file

[Tue Sep 10 10:21:06.563236 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4372:tid 812] AH00428: Parent: child process 6740 exited with status 3221226356 -- Restarting.
[Tue Sep 10 10:21:06.830367 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4372:tid 812] AH00455: Apache/2.4.39 (Win64) PHP/7.2.18 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Sep 10 10:21:06.830367 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4372:tid 812] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC15 Server built: Mar 28 2019 11:59:33
[Tue Sep 10 10:21:06.831361 2019] [core:notice] [pid 4372:tid 812] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.39\bin\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.39'
[Tue Sep 10 10:21:06.834999 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4372:tid 812] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 12400
[Tue Sep 10 10:21:07.272319 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 12400:tid 752] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Tue Sep 10 10:31:37.346310 2019] [core:alert] [pid 12400:tid 1236] [client ::1:58979] C:/wamp64/www/magento/.htaccess: Invalid command '

Comment: Open wamp/logs/apache-error.log and see what errors are display within this file and post it with your initial question as this error message is generic

Comment: Did this and it has fixed  I went to the C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.39\conf\httpd.conf file and uncommented (removing the # sign) from the LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so line.

Comment: Glad it is all sorted for you